# Changing symbols not found for selection in ArcGIS web map?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

Here are two screenshots which will show what I am expecting to get. I am looking for **change symbols** in the more options tile enlisted in the **content** tab.

[image]

I am expecting to be led to another window which may look like this

[image]

Can you advise me in this situation?

Comment: Where were these new screenshots taken from?  I don't see any context menu with Change Symbols option, but only the icon as shown in my answer below.  The Change Symbols option as you've shown in your second screenshot is available dependant on the type of data and symbol style used.  If you don't have an attribute that you can classify then you won't get those options.

Comment: I have found these screen shots from some reference docs which I have. I inserted it here for your reference as I know these are the options I wanted to be moved on; but unable to find.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a few more screenshots of what I can find in my ArcGIS Online account that is similar (although not identical) to your updated screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the third icon from the left, which will have the tooltip "Change Style" - this will allow you to set display and symbol properties for your layer.

[image]

Once you click you will be given the options to choose the field to symbolise by (if any), and then the type of symbols

[image]

Choose your field and the symbol style and select Options to be presented with a list of attributes and symbols.

[image]

Click on a symbol to select a new symbol

[image]

---

**Update showing different options similar to the ones in your question**
Depending on the type of values and features you will be given different options for symbology when you click on the Change Style icon.  In this example I have chosen a different layer and selected a field with a range of numeric values.  This time it has given a few more symbol styles to choose from.

[image]

If I pick "Counts and Amounts (Colors)" I am then presented with more settings I can configure to display my symbols how I want them, including classifying (as in your screenshots).  The Symbols icon on the right allows you to change the symbol look as well.

[image]

So although my screenshots don't match yours exactly (perhaps they are from an earlier release of ArcGIS Online?), I think you'll be able to get the same or similar options if your layer supports the type of symbol style you are wanting to use.  I have used point layers in my examples, but potentially there could be other styles available if you have lines/polygons and rasters

Answer (score 2):

Click on highlighted icon below, then click **Options** and proceed to select the symbol :

[image]